# Real Time Streaming Across WAN -> WiFi (No site-to-site or point-to-point)

Tags: networking, streaming, video-streaming

I am planning out a church campus extension. Ideally, we were bringing in a point-to-point fiber circuit, but this is impossible so I am looking at less ideal solutions now. I am open to any and all ideas, so please do not hesitate to share!

Site A has a 150/150 fiber connection and a Fortigate200D. All video and audio is mixed here in 1080p from 3 cameras. All connections are wired/ethernet/fiber.

Site B has a guest wifi network. Yup. We cannot touch any gear, we can only use their guest wifi. They are willing to allow us to penetrate their firewall, web filter, and proxy and prioritize our traffic.

What are my options? Off the top of my head:

1. A cloud service which we stream too, which spools the stream. Then we delay and download stream at site B.
2. Stream across the WAN and guest wifi in 720P and pray the internet doesnt drop and latency doesn't kill us.
3. Find a new location to extend a satellite into (not ideal).

If you know of any case studies, or services, please share.

Comment: What's the video for? Are you grabbing streams from security cameras, or are clients pulling video streams as part of some kind of service? In short, I need to know a little more about your use case to provide a sound recommendation.

Comment: We will be streaming the sermons and worship from one location to another, or in both directions. Basically, whichever campus the pastor is at will be the streaming source, and it will be streamed onto screans at the other campus. Music and stream video of the worship service will be form Site A -> B initially, but that might evolve. There will be no public viewing, no multicast- it is all internal only point to point.